# Logarithms rules using Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion, recreational-mathematics

I am wondering about a proof of additivity of natural logarithm $$\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$$ using the power series $$\ln(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^n.$$ Since this power series converges only in $x\in(0, 2],$ usually this does not use as "the" definition.
Is there any (nice) way to prove this using only the power series (not exponential function)?

One possible idea is [invert the power series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to get another power series $p(x)$ that converges everywhere and has the property $p(x+y)=p(x)p(y)$ (via Cauchy products) and use it to derive the desire result. But this is not what I am looking for. Because  I do not want exponentials anywhere in the proof. Probably something analogous to Cauchy products would do the job.

Comment: It's easy to prove using power series that $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a) \exp (b)$, which would amount to the same thing.

Comment: I am looking for a direct proof without using Exponentiation.

Comment: The given series converges for $x\in(0,2]$.

Comment: @egreg: Ohh.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered this old question, I thought to answer it myself. But all your answers based on different ideas are still welcome. Note that $$\ln x=(x-1)-\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(x-1)^3}{3}-\dfrac{(x-1)^4}{4}+\cdots $$ implies that $\ln (1)=0$ and, by term by term differentiation $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=1-(x-1)+(x-1)^2-(x-1)^3+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{x}$$ for all $x\in (0,2).$ The second equality follows from the sum of an infinite geometric series. Hence for any appropriate constant $a,$ we have $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln ax)=\dfrac{1}{ax}.a=\dfrac{1}{x}$$ by the chain rule. This implies $$\ln (ax)=\ln (x)+C$$ for some constant $C$ and by evaluating both sides at $x=1$ we get the desired result.